# Set Rotation throughout application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

Is there a way to set the application's orientation (not just in one activity) programatically?

Comment: +1, I've not been able to find an answer to this so I'll be very happy if someone knows something!

Comment: Is a base `Activity` class (where you set the screen orientation), which all other activities extending, a suitable solution?

Comment: @Pompe de velo Do you mean, `Main extends Activity` , `Activity2 extends Main` and so on?

Comment: @louieansonng: Exactly. Otherwise, can't you add the `screenOrientation` attribute to the `application` tag in the manifest file?

Comment: @Pompe de velo I think this will work for all classes that are activities, but what about listactivies and the like? I'm adding an implementation of the auto-rotate function of a device inside the app, and I think that the toggle button I placed wasn't working at all.

Comment: @louieansonng: I don't prefer `ListActivity`. I should go with composition (use `ListView` as a member field).

Answer (score 1):

write every activity onCreate() method

```
//---change to landscape mode---
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

//---change to portrait mode---
         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

may be work..